# Grails load gsp to a parameter

Tags: grails, view

I have a grails application from which I'm required to send an Email. I'm using Mandrill so that I have the freedom to send html as String to mandrill to be sent as mail. Now I have a view as below

```
example.gsp
<html>
   <header> ${subject} </header>
   <body> Hello ${user} </body>
</html>
```

If there a way I could get this into a variable with the values I require. I'm looking for a method as described below

```
String html = load(view:'example.gsp',params[subject:'test',user:'test user'])
```

So that I could pass this parameter to be sent to Mandrill to be sent as email.
Please let me know about any input on this issue

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after a bit more research. I'll post this answer in case anyone else stumbles on to this requirement.

In service Method :

```
groovyPageRenderer.render(view: 'view', model: model)
```

In Controller :

```
g.include(view: view, model: model)
```